# Date format from Apex variable in VF

Tags: visualforce, date, formatting

```
apex:variable var="Expiry" value="{!if((TEXT(object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c)!=null && TEXT(object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c)!=''),object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c,
        object.Expiry__c)}" 

             {!IF((object.Expiry__c== true),'Exp. Date: '&TEXT(Expiry), '')}
```

the code runs fine. but displays date in a yyyy/mm/dd format. How can I change the format to dd/mm/yyyy in Vf ?
Executed_Expiry_Date__c and Expiry__c are date fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format like below

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}" >
    <apex:param value="{!object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c }" />
</apex:outputText>
```

---

### Updates 2

```
<apex:variable var="Expiry" value="{!if((TEXT(object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c)!=null && TEXT(object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c)!=''),object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c,
    object.Expiry__c)}" />
<tr>
  <td>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!object.Expiry__c}">
        'Exp. Date: '
        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}" >
            <apex:param value="{!Expiry}" />
        </apex:outputText>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yes that I can but I am not displaying {!object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c } directly I am taking that in a variable first

Comment: @AfrozKazi check my updates

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i need to check one more condition 
 {!IF((object.Expiry__c== true),'Exp. Date: '&TEXT(Expiry), '')}
this is where the value from variable is displayed on the screen.

So the code has to work like this if expiry__c is true then check if executed expiry is having any value in it if it does print the same else print expiry date and for expiry__c false print nothing.

Comment: @AfrozKazi check my updates 2

Answer (score 0):

When using a var you can access its data in the following manner:

```
<apex:variable var="Expiry" value="{!if((TEXT(object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c)!=null && TEXT(object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c)!=''),object.Executed_Expiry_Date__c, object.Expiry__c)}"/>

<apex:outputText value="{0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}" >
    <apex:param value="{!Expiry}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

This will allow you to modify the var conditions but still receive the same output you are looking for.

Have a look at the [JavaDocs for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for the various date formats.

Comment: but before printing the value i need to check one more thing
{!IF((object.Expiry__c== true),'Exp. Date: '&TEXT(Expiry), '')}

Comment: Is your question based on formatting the output or are you looking for extra answers? If so I would raise a new question but for now I believe your question to formatting is answered.