# Date format is not the same in Chrome and Explorer

Tags: visualforce, date

I printing out a date field, and normally the format is based on the user local setting (i am using french settings). 
the problem is that in chrome browser, the format is correct 'DD/MM/YYYY', but in the explorer the format is 'YYYY-MM-DD', that is weird.

Here is my code visualforce:

```
 <apex:input style="margin-right:20px" label="{!$Label.Date}" value="{!displayedWeek}" id="displayedWeek" type="date">
```

what shoud i change to get the correct format in both browsers ?

Comment: Please try `<apex:inputField>` instead of `<apex:input>`. Let me know if that works

Comment: With apex:input it uses HTML-5 date format which depends on user's machine (unless a browser overrides, here chrome does). For changing setting in internet explorer, refer [this](http://www.sysprobs.com/change-date-format-windows-7-ddmmyyyy) post. Ideally if you want to keep same behaviour everywhere, either use apex:inputField or some jQuery plugin.

Comment: I can not use InputField because it's not a standard object, it's giving an error when i try that.

Answer (score 1):

Use apex:outputText with the date method of the Datetime class and a valid [date and time pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#date-and-time-patterns) string:

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"></apex:outputText>
```

Where `value` is a [FormatElement](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/MessageFormat#patterns-and-their-interpretation) with the following syntax:

> {argumentIndex, formatType, formatStyle}
>
> The ArgumentIndex value is a non-negative integer written using the digits '0' through '9', and represents an index into the arguments array passed to the format methods or the result array returned by the parse methods.
>
> The FormatType and FormatStyle values are used to create a Format instance for the format element.

**References**

- [apex:outputText | Visualforce Developer Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)
- [Datetime Class: date() method | Apex Developer Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_date)
- [Expressions | Apex Developer Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_understanding.htm)
- [Primitive Data Types | Apex Developer Guide | Salesforce Developers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm)
- [VisualForce Markup Language Server | visualforceTags.ts](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/blob/master/packages/salesforcedx-visualforce-markup-language-server/src/parser/visualforceTags.ts)
- [MessageFormat (icu4j)](http://icu-project.org/applets/icu4j/4.1/docs-4_1_3/com/ibm/icu/text/MessageFormat.html)
- [TextUtil.java | escapeForMessageFormat](https://github.com/salesforce/grammaticus/blob/master/src/main/java/com/force/i18n/commons/text/TextUtil.java#L532)
- [Click-to-Cloud | Template.apex
  : Evaluates templates written in visualforce expression syntax](https://github.com/Click-to-Cloud/Template.apex)
- [Date and Number Format in Visualforce Page. ~ Salesforce Tutorials](http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/07/date-and-number-format-using.html)
- [Date format from Apex variable in VF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149868/)